# filter having issues with tuples

Tags: python, numpy, filter

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 304, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 904, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1748, in _init_draw        
    self._draw_frame(frame_data)
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1767, in _draw_frame       
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nitro-pc\Desktop\fluid simulatio\test 5.py", line 309, in update
    velocity_x, velocity_y = project(vx_updated, vy_updated, mask)  # Ensure mask is used in projection if required
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nitro-pc\Desktop\fluid simulatio\test 5.py", line 257, in project
    div = filter(div, (width, width))  # Ensure width is passed as a tuple
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nitro-pc\Desktop\fluid simulatio\test 5.py", line 251, in filter
    diffused_f = gaussian_filter(f, width)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\autograd\tracer.py", line 48, in f_wrapped
    return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\nitro-pc\Desktop\fluid simulatio\test 5.py", line 209, in gaussian_filter
    return scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(x, sigma, mode='reflect')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_filters.py", line 375, in gaussian_filter  
    axes = [(axes[ii], sigmas[ii], orders[ii], modes[ii], radiuses[ii])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nitro-pc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\_filters.py", line 376, in <listcomp>       
    for ii in range(num_axes) if sigmas[ii] > 1e-15]
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And I believe it relates to these sections, but I can't figure out the issue:

```
@autograd.extend.primitive
def gaussian_filter(x, sigma):
    # Ensure sigma is a tuple with length equal to x's number of dimensions
    if np.isscalar(sigma):
        sigma = (sigma,) * x.ndim  # Make sigma a tuple with the same value for all dimensions
    return scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(x, sigma, mode='reflect')

def _gaussian_filter_vjp(ans, x, sigma):
    return lambda g: autograd.numpy.sum(g * ans)

autograd.extend.defvjp(gaussian_filter, _gaussian_filter_vjp)

def filter(f, width):
    if np.isscalar(width):
        width = (width,) * f.ndim  # Ensure width is a tuple
    diffused_f = gaussian_filter(f, width)
    return diffused_f
```

I've tried to modify the filters, but the issue seems circular.

```
@autograd.extend.primitive
def gaussian_filter(x, sigma):
    # Ensure sigma is a tuple with length equal to x's number of dimensions
    if np.isscalar(sigma):
        sigma = (sigma,) * x.ndim
    return scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(x, sigma, mode='reflect')

def _gaussian_filter_vjp(ans, x, sigma):
    return lambda g: autograd.numpy.sum(g * ans)

autograd.extend.defvjp(gaussian_filter, _gaussian_filter_vjp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The traceback is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry this is the missing part:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: try printing width right above this line `diffused_f = gaussian_filter(f, width)`

Comment: ok that seems to shed some light, the tuple is all false: Width before calling gaussian_filter: (array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,

Comment: `sigmas[ii]` is an array (with more than one value).  Your ` if np.isscalar(sigma)` makes a single number into a tuple, but what if `sigma` is already an array, or a tuple of arrays?

Comment: tried this to account for it being an array but nothing `def gaussian_filter(x, sigma):
    # If sigma is a scalar, convert it to a tuple with the same value for all dimensions
    if np.isscalar(sigma):
        sigma = (sigma,) * x.ndim
    # If sigma is a list or an array, ensure it has the same length as x.ndim
    elif isinstance(sigma, (list, np.ndarray)) and len(sigma) != x.ndim:
        raise ValueError("Sigma must have the same length as the number of dimensions of x")
    return scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(x, sigma, mode='reflect')`

Comment: Seems that width is not being correctly made into an array, not sure how to fix it, seems explicit in the code

Comment: don't put code in a comment.